# Make 3d objects from 3 projections in 3D Studio Max

Tags: projections, interpolation

In the early 3D Studio days before it got Max in its name it was possible to make a 3d object by defining its projections in xy, xz and yz plane. 3ds would then interpolate a 3d object from the projections. I cannot remember what was the name of this method and how it was exactly done, so I don't know which words to google. Essentially I want to use this method in Max if it is possible anymore. Can somebody give me a hint for keywords or even better explain the procedure in 3ds max?